# How I can run django cronjob function on windows?

Tags: django, django-models, cron

I'm developing a Django application which fetches an external API and stores information from that API to a local Django model so I have set a cronjob to automatically fetch and store data within some period of time.

**but the problem is this that cronjobs don't work on windows.**

So is there any way I can test my function that it will work on production on linux server.
(I'm not using windows task scheduler because I'll have to host it on linux based server.)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Use Linux for development? Or at least WSL 2?